# React Navigation - How to nest a component wrapping a stack navigator inside a tab navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to have a tab navigator, where the settings screen/tab is a component, that, among other stuff, contains a stack navigator.

Here is the code I currently have (can also be found [as a snack](https://snack.expo.io/@julianassmann/react-navigation---nest-wrapped-stack-navigator-inside-a-tab-navigator)).

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class ScreenA extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'A',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Screen A</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsHome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingsScreenA')}>
        <Text>Navigate to Settings A</Text>
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreenA extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Settings A</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingsA')}>
          <Text>Back to SettingsHome</Text>
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const SettingsStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SettingsHome: { screen: SettingsHome },
  SettingsScreenA: { screen: SettingsScreenA }
})

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Some other components...</Text>
        <SettingsStackNavigator navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  ScreenA: { screen: ScreenA },
  Settings: {screen: SettingsScreen },
});

const Navigation = createAppContainer(RootTabNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigation />
    );
  }
}
```

I currently get a 'Type Error: No "routes" found in navigation state' error. Did you try to pass the navigation prop of a React component '

Comment: Rendering `SettingsStackNavigator ` ... actually renders a screen (which is the one on top of that stack) ... why do you want have a stackNavigator + Other component in one screen ... ?

Comment: Because my client wants a different UI for portrait and landscape mode and i need to implement it in this way :(

Comment: **Some Other Components** will be placed on top of the Header of your `SettingsStackNavigator ` ... is that what you want ?

Comment: Yes, but I can't do it with the title bar of the stack navigator

Comment: I guess the applicable solution here is to embed your `Some other components` into your `SettingsHome ` and `SettingsScreenA` ++ disable the default Header for your StackNavigator .. and create a custom one instead to be placed in the middle of your components...

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to nest the component itself in a `stackNavigator`, containing the all the `stackScreen`, like so;

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class ScreenA extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'A',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', flex:1}}>
        <Text>Screen A</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsHome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingsScreenA')}
        title ="Navigate to Settings A"
      />
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreenA extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', flex:1}}>
        <Text>Settings A</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingsHome')}
          title ="Back to SettingsHome"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', flex:1}}>
        <Text>Some other components...</Text>
          <Button title="Seting A" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingsScreenA')} />

      </View>
    );
  }
}

// Create our stack navigator
const SettingsStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SettingsMain: {screen: SettingsScreen,},
  SettingsHome: { screen: SettingsHome },
  SettingsScreenA: { screen: SettingsScreenA }
}, {initialRouteName: 'SettingsMain'})



const RootTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  ScreenA: { screen: ScreenA },
  Settings: {screen: SettingsStackNavigator },
});

// And the app container
export default createAppContainer(RootTabNavigator);
```

hope it helps!